# (Background-size: Cover) overlaying padding

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for help towards `background-size: cover;`

So the problem I'm having is that I've got padding on my image box's but having the background image set in `CSS` seems to have the image covering the image box padding instead of having inside the padding.

I was wondering if there is any way of doing it through `background: url()` and `background-size` and having it inside the padding instead of overlaying the padding.

What i have so far:

```css
.image-container {
  background: #eee;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
}

.image-container div.image {
  background: #ee1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 4px 0px;
  background: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/14621/Warsaw-at-night-free-license-CC0.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you not use margins instead of padding?

Comment: hey Chris do you want this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ctLwrz0c/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a border instead of padding.

Something like:

```
.image-container div.image {
  padding: 4px 0px; /* remove this */
  ...
  border-top: 4px solid transparent; /* or whatever color */
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent; /* or whatever color */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```css
.image-container {
  background: #eee;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
}

.image-container div.image {
  background: #ee1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  border-top: 4px solid green; /* using a color just for demo. */
  border-bottom: 4px solid green; /* using a color just for demo. */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/14621/Warsaw-at-night-free-license-CC0.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

From the above demo snippet you can see that the border is **above** the image.